# Activate System.Data.SQLClient library in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with a Unity project.
I want to connect to a database, but my project doesn't recognize the System.Data.SQLClient library. I tried to install it, but it still doesn't recognize it. I would like you to help me please to enable it.

[image: Unity Project]

Code:
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;


public class Conexion : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region metodo
    public static SqlConnection conectar()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog =juego;" + "User ID=sa; Password=123";
        //+ "Integrated Security=true;";
        return cn;
    }
    #endregion metodo
}
```

`

[image]

[image]

Enable SQLClient library in Unity
Enable SQLClient library in Unity

Comment: Off-topic: terrible idea (you should rather make some rest midleware for this ... only exuse for using sql connection directly is some busines app in closed intranet not game(?)) ... Anyway, did you add right package ?

Comment: I have this plugin in Unity, but I don't know how to activate it to make it work https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mGZF.png

Comment: @Selvin looks like OP is talking about a local database file compiled into the app itself though

Comment: @derHugo Yes, a local database

Comment: @derHugo Connection string doesn't shows "local database file" but local instance ... Well, game which requeries local instance of SQL server ... brillant idea

Comment: This is the error that appears when I use the library https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN6Rb.png

Comment: do you get the error only in Visual Studio or also within the Unity console?

Comment: Both, Unity and Visual

Comment: I would normally ask you to not post images of error messages but in this case it doesn't really matter because it's all Spanish. Kind of hard to understand.